# The Center of Mass of a solid quadrant.

Tags: calculus

I have found via integration that the y coordinate is $$y =h/2 = 120 mm$$. The x coordinate is $$x = \frac{-4r}{3\pi} = -51.9mm$$ and the z coordinate is $$z = r -  \frac{4r}{3\pi} = 69.1 mm$$. I have no answers in my textbook so cant confirm whether i am correct or not, if i am incorrect could i please have a little push.[image]

Comment: What do you mean "CM"?? If you mean "Center of Mass", your solution is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The centroid lies on the intersection of any (i.e. both) planes of symmetry. So clearly your $y$ value is correct. The formula $\frac{4r}{3\pi}$ gives the distance to the centroid of the quadrant from the the vertical and horizontal axes. You just need to check the calculation for $x$. I get $-50.9$.